# camelCased Model names

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

does anyone know if there is a recent problem with camelcased properties.

I have a model like this:

```
var attr = DS.attr;

App.Users = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: attr('string'),
    phone: attr('string'),
    email: attr('string')
});
```

In my template email and phone show up correctly but firstName doesnt appear. I checked the json file  and everything seems to be fine. With all my other models the same problems appear, 
so i guess it has to do something with the camelCase.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `firstName: DS.attr('string'), ...`?

Comment: It should definitely work. The json response from the server contains 'first_name' or 'firstName' ?

Comment: if your json is giving you `firstName`, you'll have to work on your adapter/serializer to map it to the property in the Model

Comment: The json response from the server contains firstName.

Comment: I think you'll have to do something like this: `DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.User', { firstName: 'firstName' });` and I think the model name should be in the singular.

Comment: What i don't understand then, why phone and email are shown correctly and just all my camelCased properties are failing ?

Comment: because they have the exact same name in both your Model and the JSON response. Ember.js relies on naming [conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_json-conventions), and it expects that multiple-word-camel-case (e.g. `firstName`) model properties to be mapped to multiple-word-underscore-separated-lower-case (e.g. `first_name`) attributes on the JSON response.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Ready to put your comments together in an answer ? :)

Comment: @sly7_7 I responded as comment 'cause it was mostly questions and hints, but there it is.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Yeah I understand, I think now your answer fits perfectly to his question. Thanks for taking time :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Deprecation Notice: This answer is from 2013, and hasn't been touched up until now. This does not reflect JSON API Adapter but rather Ember-Data's RESTAdapter.**

Ember.js relies on [naming conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_json-conventions), and it expects that multiple-word-camel-case (e.g. `firstName`) model properties to be mapped to multiple-word-underscore-separated-lower-case  attributes (e.g. `first_name`) on the JSON response. If your JSON is giving you `firstName`, or anything that is not in this convention in a scenario that you **do not** control the backend API, you have the option of defining a `map` which tells your adapter to look for a specific key in the JSON response and map it to a property in a given Model.

You can do something like this:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.User', { 
    firstName: { key: 'firstName' },
    lastName: { key: 'familyName' }
});
```

Note that in the sample above I've added a `lastName` property which is not part of your own model. I've done that just to make it clear that you can map several properties at the same time, and its name in the JSON response can be anything, not necessarily the same name in a different casing.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Is there a more current way of doing this?  I get the error `TypeError: DS.RESTAdapter.map is not a function` when I load the page

Comment: @NathanHanna sadly no. I have looked into it, but I'm not up to date with the framework for about 6 months now so I can't really help here :(

Comment: Currently the JSON API does no longer use the `underscore` but the `hyphen-minus` char. See for more info: http://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#naming.