# Ember: ASync belongs to doesn't seem to resolve

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following two models:

models/profile.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

models/user.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  profile: DS.belongsTo('profile', {async:true})
});
```

The user models is loaded by a user service, based on a cookie set by the server when the user authenticates:

services/user.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    store: Ember.inject.service('store'),
    init: function() {
        var _this = this;
        _this.set('user', null)
        if(Cookies.get('uid')) {
            _this.get('store').findRecord('user', Cookies.get('uid')).then(function(user) {
                console.log(user)
                _this.set('user', user)
            }, function(err) {
                console.warn(err);
                Cookies.remove('uid')
                _this.set('user', null)
            });
        } else {
            _this.set('user', null)
        }
    }
});
```

The user service is injected into the application controller:

controllers/applications.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    user: Ember.inject.service('user')
});
```

I have some debugging output in my main template

templates/application.hbs

```
{{#if user.user}}
    <h2 id="title">Welcome to Ember {{user.user}} # {{user.user.id}} # {{user.user.profile}} # {{user.user.profile.firstName}}</h2>
{{else}}
    <h2 id="title">Please Log In <a href="/auth/linkedin">Linkedin</a></h2>
{{/if}}

{{outlet}}
```

which when I authenticate and load the page outputs

```
Welcome to Ember <project@model:user::ember418:5663bfe19d78ce048784a098> # 5663bfe19d78ce048784a098 # <DS.PromiseObject:ember419> #
```

I can see requests made to my api endpoints in the console, first for the user then for the profile, as expected:

http://localhost:3000/api/users/5663bfe19d78ce048784a098

```
{
    links: {
        self: "http://localhost:3000/api/users/5663bfe19d78ce048784a098"
    },
    data: {
        id: "5663bfe19d78ce048784a098",
        type: "users",
        attributes: {
            providers: [{
                provider: "linkedin",
                id: "ECixxxxqc9",
                displayName: "John Smith",
                name: {
                    familyName: "Smith",
                    givenName: "John"
                }
            }]
        },
        links: {
            self: "/users/5663bfe19d78ce048784a098"
        },
        relationships: {
            profile: {
                data: {
                    type: "profiles",
                    id: "5663c05f5fd3331387307e89"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://localhost:3000/api/profiles/5663c05f5fd3331387307e89

```
{
    links: {
        self: "http://localhost:3000/api/profiles/5663c05f5fd3331387307e89"
    },
    data: {
        id: "5663c05f5fd3331387307e89",
        type: "profiles",
        attributes: {
            active: true,
            yearsExperience: 9,
            lastName: "Smith",
            firstName: "John"
        },
        links: {
            self: "/profiles/5663c05f5fd3331387307e89"
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like the `user.user.profile` promise isn't being resolved, hence the `<DS.PromiseObject:ember419>` output and no value for `user.user.profile.firstName`.  Is there something I'm missing in the model definitions or is there something I need to call to manually tell the controller/template that a belongsTo has been resolved?

---

Updates:
I tried to add a reference from profile to user, however the results are the same

For reference,

new /models/profile.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

new http://localhost:3000/api/profiles/5663c05f5fd3331387307e89

```
{
    links: {
        self: "http://localhost:3000/api/profiles/5663c05f5fd3331387307e89"
    },
    data: {
        id: "5663c05f5fd3331387307e89",
        type: "profiles",
        attributes: {
            active: true,
            yearsExperience: 9,
            lastName: "Smith",
            firstName: "John"
        },
        links: {
            self: "/profiles/5663c05f5fd3331387307e89"
        },
        relationships: {
            user: {
                data: {
                    type: "users",
                    id: "5663bfe19d78ce048784a098"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Grasping at straws a bit here, but does it help if you define the other side of that relationship, I.e. add the `user` relationship to your `profile` model? Either just in the Ember code or also in the API response...

Comment: @Thernys I'll give it a try when I'm home from work today

Comment: @Thernys Took me much longer than expected, but managed to get around to it. Unfortunately didn't solve the problem, I'll update the question with additional information about what I tried in case other have suggestions. Thank you for trying to help out though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my problem is not what I think it is...

I added a "first" attribute to profile and it works fine, it seems that all attributes that are in camelCase aren't getting populated, which is another issue

model with "first", /models/profile.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  yearsExperience: DS.attr('number'),
  active: DS.attr('boolean'),
  first: DS.attr('string')
});
```

endpoint with "first", http://localhost:3000/api/profiles/5663c05f5fd3331387307e89

```
{
    links: {
        self: "http://localhost:3000/api/profiles/5663c05f5fd3331387307e89"
    },
    data: {
        id: "5663c05f5fd3331387307e89",
        type: "profiles",
        attributes: {
            active: true,
            yearsExperience: 9,
            lastName: "Smith",
            firstName: "John",
            first: "John!"
        },
        links: {
            self: "/profiles/5663c05f5fd3331387307e89"
        },
        relationships: {
            user: {
                data: {
                    type: "users",
                    id: "5663bfe19d78ce048784a098"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

updated /templates/application.hbs

```
{{#if user.user}}
    <h2 id="title">Welcome to Ember {{user.user}} # {{user.user.id}} # {{user.user.profile}} # {{user.user.profile.firstName}} # {{user.user.profile.first}}</h2>
{{else}}
    <h2 id="title">Please Log In <a href="/auth/linkedin">Linkedin</a></h2>
{{/if}}

{{outlet}}
```

renders as

```
Welcome to Ember <prohacvice@model:user::ember428:5663bfe19d78ce048784a098> # 5663bfe19d78ce048784a098 # <DS.PromiseObject:ember427> # # John!
```

This indicates to me that the issue isn't with the belongsTo resolving, but rather some values (the ones with camelCase) not being properly set. I'll do some research into that and if necessary post an appropriate question for it

Comment: Using dash separators (via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552117/camelcased-model-names) seems to work fine